# Samsung Galaxy S I1500 Stuck on boot screen

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s

I have this used Verizon Galaxy S, and one day it locked up on the home screen, and when i rebooted it, it was stuck on the boot screen, is my phone completely cooked or is there a way to fix this?

edit: here's  video https://youtu.be/8E9orCfVaFg

Comment: Did it happen once or is still stuck?

Comment: Is it stuck on the very first boot screen that appears after powering it on?

Comment: Hey! thanks for the questions. Yes, it's still happening, and it doesn't get past the Verizon logo where it keeps playing the boot animation, i'll have to post a video about it so i can show you what's going on.